# Не работает оператор

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Всем привет, начал изучать пайтон по книге, и пошла речь по оператору break, то код не запускается, в чем проблема?

```
while True:
    s = input('Введите что-то:')
    if s == 'Выход':
       break
     print('Длина строки:', len(s))
print ('Завершение  ')
```

Comment: Перед `break` у вас 3 пробела, должно быть 4. И перед `print('Длина строки:', len(s))` 1 лишний.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде есть ошибки, из-за них код и не работает.

Вот исправленный и рабочий код:

```
while True:
    s = input('Введите что-то:')
    if s == 'Выход':
        break
    print('Длина строки:', len(s))
print('Завершение  ')
```

Ошибки:
1. Лишний пробел перед строкой:

```
print('Длина строки:', len(s))
```

2. Перед break 7 пробелов, а должно быть 8.

И еще есть недочеты:
1. Между последним print и круглой скобкой не должно быть пробела.
2. Ну и вообще по хорошему в самом конце кода у вас должна быть пустая строка.

Comment: 2 - не ошибка, а всего лишь нарушение рекомендаций по стилю кода. Как и 3.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну это смотря как посмотреть.. Если работать в компании, где соблюдают стиль, тогда это ошибка. Меня на работе за такое не хвалили, когда только учился :)

Comment: @Эникейщик но в любом случае, я все поправил. Так лучше? :)

Comment: Получше :) ....